How can I make an array of objects by the id from a long obj list?
I have an object like this from an api.
{
  "32111" { ...object}
  "83276" { ...object}
...
}

How can I convert this to an array for each number ?
like this
``
[
{
id: "32111"
...
},
{
id: "83276"
}
]

The api gives me only a whole object of strings with ids but not a array. How can I convert this to an array?


Object.keys + map should handle this pretty easily.

Object.keys(response).map(key => ({id:key})) as comment above

You can use static Object methods.
const obj = {   
   "32111":  { "name": "One" }
   "83276":  { "name": "Two }
}
const keys = Object.keys(obj) // ["32111", "83276"]
const values = Object.values(obj) // [value, value]
const entries = Object.entries(obj) 
// [
//    ["32111", { "name": "One" }],
//    ["83276",  { "name": "Two }]
//

Then you can operate on them as Arrays.
entries.map(...)
keys.forEach(...) 
//...etc



const obj = {   
   "32111":  { "name": "One" },
   "83276":  { "name": "Two" }
}
const keys = Object.keys(obj); // ["32111", "83276"]
const values = Object.values(obj); // [value, value]
const entries = Object.entries(obj); 

// [
//    ["32111", { "name": "One" }],
//    ["83276",  { "name": "Two }]
// ]


console.log(entries.map(([key,value]) => `${key} is "${JSON.stringify(value)}"`))




You can map the keys to new compound objects:


const object = {prop1: 1, prop2: 2};
const data = {
  "32111" : { ...object},
  "83276" : { ...object}
}

const result = Object.keys(data).map(id => ({id, ...data[id]}));

console.log(result);



